# IOS categories - Is it ok to create dependencies between categories?

Tags: ios, categories

Is it ok to create dependencies between categories in Objective C? Also between the categories and their base class?

I know that there should be no difference at runtime, they probably are just merged together at compile-time. For instance, let us say i break down my class B into:

```
B(base class)
B+categ1
B+categ2
B+categ3
```

My question is, is it wrong to either:

```
a) import B+categ2 and B+categ3 in B.m 
b) import B+categ1 in B+categ3?
```

I'm asking both performance-wise and conceptually.

**EDIT:**

What would you suggest for a single screen app? Categories or Extending that class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing deeply wrong with it, but it may suggest an overuse of categories. While they are a powerful tool for certain problems, and definitely can create some conveniences, I generally wouldn't build a complex system on them.

I usually find that overuse of categories is based on too much [IS-A thinking rather than HAS-A thinking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance). In other words, if you're putting a lot of categories on an class to act as a fancy kind of subclassing, you may be better off using composition instead. Rather than adding lots of category methods to `NSArray` (as an example), you would want an data object that has an `NSArray` property and provides the interface you want.

But this is just advice if you're overusing categories. There's no fundamental problem with having categories import other categories. However, this claim is incorrect:

> I know that there should be no difference at runtime, they probably are just merged together at compile-time.

Categories are resolved at runtime, not compile-time. The one major danger of that is that if two categories implement the same method, then the behavior is undefined. This is why you should never use categories to override methods, only to add them.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I started using categories because I really liked the idea of adding functionality where you need it by just importing the category that you need. I recognize the danger of over usage, but, at this point, I will work a lot with single-screen apps, and the only viable option I see is to either extend the base class a bunch of times to add functionality(which seems to add a lot of unnecesarry complexity), or to create objects that do part of the work, but that means a perf. overhead in moving data around. What would you suggest is best for working with single-screen apps?

Comment: What "perf. overhead in moving data around?" Almost everything in ObjC is reference counted. There is no cost in sharing data between objects. You should generally break your project down into smaller, more focused objects. Combining these objects via composition is almost always the best design.

Comment: I was thinking of the case when you want to keep things decoupled (using notifications to pass data around), you need to marshall and unmarshall everything each time. Using delegates may be a better solution in this case.

Comment: One other question, when you say "adding functionality where you need it by just importing the category that you need," what do you mean? When you compile an app that includes category code, the category code is automatically attached to every instance of the class at load time, whether you import it or not.

Comment: If you're marshaling data for notifications, that suggests that you aren't using data objects correctly. You can post a data object in the userInfo of a notification (and should).

Comment: Sorry, by marshalling I meant creating a dictionary and populating it, then extracting the data from the dictionary on the other side. I'm guessing this does have a bit of overhead.

Comment: Yes. You should not be using a dictionary. You should use a data object. Then you don't need to marshal. Overuse of `NSDictionary` is a common problem in ObjC.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid having a base class depend on a category of itself. Exceptions to this rule are made for private categories (use extensions instead) and categories intended to be used by subclasses of the base class. These are specialized exceptions and should not be thought of as a proper general purpose solution.

For categories depending on categories, if you make sure the dependency graph never has a cycle, then you should be fine.

As a final bit of advice, be explicit about dependencies.

```
// A+c2
#import "A+c1.h" // A(c2) relies on A(c1) declared methods/properties.
…

// A+c3
#import "A+c1.h" // A(c3) relies on A(c1) declared methods/properties.
#import "A+c2.h" // A(c3) relies on A(c2) declared methods/properties.
```

Even though A(c3) is implicitly including A(c1) by importing "A+c2.h", I still explicitly import it. This will save frustration as code changes in the future.